# Can exporting site with Wp All in One Migration tool corrupt web servers?

Tags: wordpress, timeout, migration, hosting, devops

I was using [Wp All In One Migration plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) to safely download the website to my local development environment.

Can this cause the website servers to stop responding?

The message is "This site can’t be reached", "took too long to respond." ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I think it could be due to the limits of a web hosting provider. Is it possible that website export has lead to the exeeding the limits of a web hosting provider?

Can this be the issue?

Is it good practice to export website to local development enviroment and then fix issues of a site, than looking at the workflow fix issues on the live site, without website import, which could probably brake something.

Note, that I didn't do the import to the live website, only export.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of reasons for the issues you are facing.

According to my experience, most of the time this issue is caused by "redirects" applied in the site.

Answering to your other  question:

It will be more helpful if you could provide a screenshot of the issue.

Importing a site on local development environment to fix issues in the site in undoubtedly a good practice.

This makes sure that the live site is up and running and as soon as the issues are fixed, new files can be placed on the hosting server, replacing the old files.

**Note**: Keeping a backup of the old files can also be considered if one is not sure about the new code.

I hope this helps.

Regards,